# Elastic Search Regex are not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I have go the problem in making elastic search regex work. I have a document that looks like this:

```
{"content": "keySyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd"}
```

I have trying the following regex `key[0-9A-Za-z_]{18}` which perfectly matches with the string in regexer.com but when I query the request from elastic search it doesn't show any hits.

Here's the request that i'm using:

```
curl -XGET 'https://localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic redacted' -k -d '{
  "query": { "regexp": { "content": "key[0-9A-Za-z_]{18}" } }
}'
```

I have also tried the regex with `.*key[0-9A-Za-z_]{18}.*`, tried to escape `-` as `\\-` but it doesn't seems to be working as well.

Comment: Which version are you running and what's the type of the `content` field (please share the field mapping)? Works fine on 7.17 on both a keyword field or a text field

Comment: filed mapping looks like this

``` "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Elastic search version is 8.3.3

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the value of the `content` field? No space character anywhere?

Comment: Even if there are spaces the regex should match with the string for example if the string is "blablablablablabla keySyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd" the regex should match eventually with the string.

Comment: No, once you can try it, you'll see that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the regexp query against the `content.keyword` field

```
curl -XGET 'https://localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic redacted' -k -d '{
  "query": { "regexp": { "content.keyword": "key[0-9A-Za-z_]{18}" } }
}'
```

PS: easier to test and provide feedback with **real** content and **real** queries ;-)

Comment: Can you check with this string and regex
{"content": "<html> <title> <script> AIzaSyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd-xO2U_vWGVfoF5-XM </script>"} 
regex: AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35}

Comment: Now that we get to see real content, what's the **real** regexp you're using?

Comment: i'm trying this regex AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35} on the string AIzaSyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd-xO2U_vWGVfoF5-XM

Comment: In that case, you need to use this regexp `.*AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35}.*` with initial and ending wildcard, but in this case we get this error: `too_complex_to_determinize_exception: Determinizing automaton with 77 states and 358 transitions would require more than 10000 effort.`

Comment: *real* regexp is AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35}
*real* document is {"content": "<html> <title> <script> AIzaSyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd-xO2U_vWGVfoF5-XM </script>"}

Comment: I don't understand why the regex in Question works and why this **real** one does not work. Is elastic search have something different syntax?

Comment: In the question it works because the value STARTS with `key` and the regexp too. In your real content `AI` is not at the beginning of the value

Comment: You have two ways to make it work: 1) clean up the content from HTML tags so that the value starts with `AI...` and you don't have to add a leading wildcard or 2) if it's always the same HTML tags then add them to the regexp like this `\\<html\\> \\<title\\> \\<script\\> AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35}.*`

Comment: Gotch, let me try!

Comment: I even tried with {"content": "AIzaSyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd-xO2U_vWGVfoF5-XM"}
and regex AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35} and it still did not work, as you mentioned the value should start with AIza but it's still not working.

Comment: You need to use the `content.keyword` field as stated in my answer

Comment: Cool, glad it helped, looks like it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Try this:

```
curl -u elastic:password -XPOST "https://localhost:9200/test_regex/_bulk?refresh" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"content": "keySyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd"}
'
```

---

```
curl -u elastic:password -XGET "https://localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
  "query": { "regexp": { "content": "key[0-9A-Za-z_]{18}" } }
}'
```

[image]

Comment: Strange, I already have `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` in my request.

Comment: What's your elastic search version?

Comment: My ES version is 8.x

Comment: @MusabDogan I can see the Content-type header in the OP question

Comment: Yes, I just saw that too it's exist. @Captain-Robot can you please try to create a new index and try the query I shared?

Comment: @MusabDogan I tried your curl and they works but when I try it in my actual index it doesn't work I'm trying to check if this is something because of mapping or what else.

Comment: I'm trying directly in Kibana, as is, and it works without any change. @Captain-Robot can you show the "real" sample document that is supposed to match?

Comment: {"content": "<html> <title> <script>  AIzaSyAtUXpd8JxrpUH2Sd-xO2U_vWGVfoF5-XM </script>"}
that's the real sample document with the actual regex I was trying with `AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{35}` 
@MusabDogan @val

Comment: @MusabDogan can you check if the above mentioned string and regex works for you please?

Comment: Not working...

`GET test_regex/_search?pretty
{"query":{"regexp":{"content":"AIza[0-9A-Za-z-_]{36}"}}}`